# How to properly initialize the jQuery Tools' Scrollable component for a single item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I have created a web page which uses the jQuery Tools' Scrollable component, and the page is based on the [minimal setup demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html).  As in this demo my page also uses scrollable items with room for five thumbnail images, but when my page loads for the first time I want only a single scrollable item containing only three thumbnail images, with the remaining two image slots empty.  I assumed that I could simply replace the three scrollable item divs from the demo with a single scrollable item div and everything would look fine, however when I do that I end up seeing inoperable left/previous and right/next icons, even though there are no previous or next scrollable items to scroll to.

I have an example of what I'm trying to do on the jsfiddle site [here](http://jsfiddle.net/monocongo/mJZXk/).  It's essentially the above referenced demo with the non-applicable scrollable item divs and child imgs commented out.

How can I initialize the scrollable such that I only have a single scrollable item on the page without having the non-applicable left/previous and right/next icons appear?

Thanks in advance for your help, suggestions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

best I can come up with is

```
if($(".scrollable .items div").length < 2) $("a.browse").hide();
```

after the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the browse buttons to be hidden by default, then only display them if needed.

In the css, default the `a.browse` to `visibility: hidden`

Then in the initialization:

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable().each( function() {
  var scroller = $(this).data("scrollable");
  scroller.getNaviButtons().css('visibility', 'visible');
  if (scroller.getSize() <= 1) {
    scroller.getNaviButtons().addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

This seems a bit hacky, but avoids temporarily displaying the browse buttons if they are not going to be seen.